# spark Dataframe string to Hive varchar

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I read data from Oracle via spark JDBC connection to a DataFrame. I have a column which is obviously `StringType` in dataframe.

Now I want to persist this in Hive, but as datatype `Varchar(5)`. I know the string would be truncated but it is ok.

I tried using UDFs which didn't work since dataframe does not have `varchar` or `char` types. I also created a temporary view in Hive using:

```scala
val tv = df.createOrReplaceTempView("t_name")
val df = spark.sql("select cast(col_name as varchar(5)) from tv")
```

But then when i `printSchema`, i still see a `string` type.

How can I make I save it as a `varchar` column in Hive table ?

Comment: There is a `org.apache.spark.sql.types.VarcharType`. Did you try using that ?

Comment: yes, it says string cannot be casted to VarcharType

Answer (score 0):

Try creating Hive table("dbName.tableName") with required schema (varchar(5) in this case) and insert into the table directly from Dataframe like below.

```
df.write.insertInto("dbName.tableName" ,overwrite = False)
```